# How to handle 2 users place order same products at same time in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, e-commerce, acid

I'm a beginner and don't have much experience with this case. I hope everyone can help me or provide me with a solution.
Suppose, two users order the same product at the same time and there is only one product available. To handle the order, I need to do the following:

1. Use the FindOneAndUpdate method to decrease the in-stock quantity by one.
2. Create an order for the user.

It's a simple process that I want to know first. If step-2 fails, I need to roll back the operation in step 1 by increasing the in-stock quantity by one. I've created a transaction for these two operations, so if either step fails, I will abort the transaction.

Everything works fine if only one user makes an order at a specific time. However, if two or more users make an order at the same time, only the first request will be handled, and the rest will be rejected and receive an error response. In this case, I want every request to be executed sequentially.

```js
const placeOrder = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) => {
  const session = await startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  try {
    if (req.headers.isauth === '0') {
      return handleError(req, res, { code: 401, message: 'unAuthorized' });
    }
    const { address } = req.body as Omit<Address, 'defaultAdd'> & {
      defaultAdd?: boolean;
    };

    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.headers._id }, {}, { session });
    if (user) {
      // decrease product quantity
      const bulkOps = user.cart.map((item: Cart) => ({
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            _id: item.id,
            inStock: { $gte: item.quantity },
          },
          update: { $inc: { inStock: -item.quantity, sold: +item.quantity } },
        },
      }));
      const [productResponse] = await Promise.all([
        Product.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { session }),
        user.update({ cart: [] }, { session }),
        Order.create(
          [
            {
              userId: user._id.toString(),
              shippingFee: 15000, // fixed price
              address,
              products: user.cart,
            },
          ],
          { session },
        ),
      ]);
      if (productResponse.result.nModified < bulkOps.length)
        throw new Error('Out of stock');

      await session.commitTransaction();
      return res.status(200).send({ message: 'ok' });
    }
    return handleError(req, res, { code: 404, message: 'user not found' });
  } catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    return handleError(req, res, {});
  } finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo updates are atomic, means it has own queue for updates (locks) and guarantees no simultaneous updates happen to the same document.

The filter in step 1 should include a condition "in-stock quantity > 0", so even if you have multiple concurrent sales of the same (last) item, only the first update will return number of affected documents = 1, and all other updates will return 0.

Check this value on application level and proceed to step 2 only when the update was successful. All other requests will need to way for re-stocking. The best you can do for them is to send your regrets to the clientside and invite to the waiting list.

**UPDATE**

Since the OP uses transaction, it should solve the problem. The documents updated within the transaction remain exclusively locked on WiredTiger level until the transaction is committed or rejected.

All concurrent transaction will wait to lock any of these documents up to [maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis) configuration option, 5 millis by default.

If second transaction fails to acquire the lock, the driver throws a WriteConflict exception. Details are documented at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-production-consideration/#lock-request-timeout

> I found some people who have the same problem as me, but they haven't received any good solutions yet. (https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/recommended-way-to-handle-write-conflicts-inside-transactions/104491/5)

The solution is in the last post:

> If the transaction is required you should leave it in. Then if their are write-conflicts you will have to retry.

given by Mongodb employee. To elaborate - you are expected to use try-catch on application level to implement custom retries if default behaviour doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: I want to put both operations in one transaction. This is because if either step 1 or step 2 fails, I can abort the transaction and roll back to the original data. If the server executes each operation separately as you mentioned (with step 1 succeeding and step 2 failing for any reason), then the in-stock quantity will decrease by 1, even though no order has been made. This could prevent the next request from making an order with this product because of out of stock.

Comment: hmm, @Simba, it seems you already know the answer you want to hear. If you want to use transactions - use them. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: I have already used "transactions" for my use case, but as my question . When two order requests for the same product at same time, the second request is rejected while the fist is executing and returned as an error to the client (it doesn't wait for executing).I want all subsequent requests to wait until the previous request is complete and execute sequentially instead of returning an error to the client. In other words, I want all requests to be queued and executed in order. I've tried implementing this with MySQL and it works well, but I'm having trouble doing the same thing with MongoDB.

Comment: I see, it wasn't obvious from the question you are using transactions. May I ask how you tested "*it doesn't wait for executing*" part?  It should. If you update the question with an example so I could reproduce it, I am happy to file a bug to mongo. Also, what error does it return? Isn't it a write conflict by a chance?

Comment: I have updated my question with code. I am using Next.js and Mongoose. I have written a script to make two orders for the same product at the same time for testing.I found some people who have the same problem as me, but they haven't received any good solutions yet. (https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/recommended-way-to-handle-write-conflicts-inside-transactions/104491/5 )

Comment: Sorry, the snippet doesn't help at all. First of all it's not sufficient to run without models and data, secondly there are a lot of irrelevant code, like authentication, and finally it doesn't show how you test it - how do you guarantee the second transaction starts before the first finished, and that the second transaction returns an error "without waiting".  I'm afraid you need to put a bit more efforts than copy-pasting piece of your code to prove your claim that transactions are flawed.